# Vertical alignment of equation with underbrace involved

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment

could somebody please help me make the equation M, not be affected by the underbrace? I want M, the equals sign and the stuff it's equal to, to all be aligned instead of the M= being aligned with the centre, if that makes sense.  A solution that affects the current code the least would be great! Thankyou :D

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
M=& \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{array}}_\text{text} 
& \underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{array}}_\text{text} 
& \underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{array}}_\text{text} \\ 
\end{array} \\[5pt] 
=& \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
(1 & 1)(1 & 1). \\ 
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE! Delete outer array!

Comment: If your code is a very simplified version of your real situation, then it's likely insufficient for giving more advice than I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me spell out my comment: ...

**Edit:**
Removed spaces between terms in parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{aligned}
M = & \underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{array}}_\text{text}\,
      \underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{array}}_\text{text}\,
      \underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccccc}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{array}}_\text{text}    \\
  = & \begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
      (1 & 1)(1 & 1). \\
      \end{array}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or by use of `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{aligned}
M = & \underbrace{\begin{matrix}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{matrix}}_\text{text}\,
      \underbrace{\begin{matrix}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{matrix}}_\text{text}\,
      \underbrace{\begin{matrix}(1 & 1 & 1 & 1)(1 & 1 & 1 & 1) \end{matrix}}_\text{text}    \\
  = & \begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
      (1 & 1)(1 & 1). \\
      \end{array}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Is there any way of removing the gap between the first and second set of brackets? When using your approach mine has done the same thing, but my gap is much larger. Cheers.

Comment: @trieasyboid, yes. See edited answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for that - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for wrapping in an `array`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rowvec}[2][2pt]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\arraycolsep}{#1}%
  \begin{pmatrix}#2\end{pmatrix}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
M &=
  {\underbrace{
    \rowvec{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}\rowvec{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}
  }_\text{text}}
  \,
  {\underbrace{
    \rowvec{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}\rowvec{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 }
  }_\text{text}}
  \,
  {\underbrace{
    \rowvec{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}\rowvec{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 }
  }_\text{text}}
\\
&=
\rowvec{1 & 1}\rowvec{1 & 1}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response :D. I've never used the new command function before so I wouldn't really know what this is doing. Although I do like the use of the rowvec! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`pmatrix` is easy to use for this:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
    
  \newcommand{\pmatn}[1]{\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
  \begin{align*}
  M &= \underbrace{\pmatn{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}\pmatn{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}}_\text{text} \, 
       \underbrace{\pmatn{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}\pmatn{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}}_\text{text} \,
       \underbrace{\pmatn{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}\pmatn{1 & 1 & 1 & 1}}_\text{text} \\  
    &= \pmatn{1 & 1}\pmatn{1 & 1}
  \end{align*}
    
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your response. I've never used the \newcommand function before, although I do see a lot of people using it so I should probably learn. Thanks for your reply though.